# Can't debug Go in VSCode - cannot find GOROOT directory: /snap/bin/go

Tags: linux, go, visual-studio-code, snap

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, VSCode 1.62.3, go 1.17.3 linux/amd64

When I start the debugger in VSCode it shows me this warning

> The "dlv-dap" command is not available. Please select "install", or
> follow the installation instructions here. Source: Go (Extension) [Install] [Install All]

I click Install and see that in the output:

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/home/raspberry/GolandProjects
Installing 1 tool at /home/raspberry/GolandProjects/bin in module mode.
  dlv-dap

Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 2,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go get -x -d github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /snap/bin/go\n"
}

1 tools failed to install.

dlv-dap: failed to install dlv-dap(github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go get -x -d github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /snap/bin/go
```

When I check GOROOT by the go tool I see that:

```
$ go env GOROOT
/usr/local/go
```

When I check /snap/bin/ I see that:

```
~$ cd /snap/bin/
:/snap/bin$ ls
canonical-livepatch  pre-commit.validate-config
go                   pre-commit.validate-manifest
gofmt                snap-store
go.gofmt             snap-store.ubuntu-software
pre-commit           snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
```

I'm confused, there is /snap/bin/go but VSCode tells me that there is not and fails to run the debugger. How to fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

When I set GOROOT to /snap/bin/go by typing this into the console:

```
$ export GOROOT=/snap/bin/go
```

VSCode starts to print that when I try to run the debugger:

```
Couldn't find dlv-dap at the Go tools path, /home/raspberry/GolandProjects/, /home/raspberry/GolandProjects or /usr/local/go/bin:/home/raspberry/.local/bin:/home/raspberry/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
Follow the setup instruction in https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#getting-started.
```

Answer (score 13):

So, here is the fix - add to VSCode `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` this line

```
"go.goroot": "/snap/go/current"
```

Here is the explanation - https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/166

Answer (score 0):

Below is exact path to navigate and add
in VSCode go to
File-> Preferences-> Settings-> Extension-> Go
you will find edit as json button.
Add this code in that place
[image]